# For each positive $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and for each $y \in\mathbb{R}$ there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y < nx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm not sure where the connection lies. I have proven the following:

**Lemma 1**:
For each $z \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $z < n$.

My professor has said that the proof requires some algebraic manipulation and an application of Lemma 1.
I wanted to approach the proof as a proof by cases. I have only the Field Axioms, Ordered Field Axioms, Upperbound Definition , Maximum Definition and Least Upper Bound Definition. I'm not sure what he meant by algebraic manipulation and have been hesitant on starting the proof.

Comment: Multiply the inequality $z<n$ by some positive $x>0$ and define $y=zx$. By the given axioms ($\mathbb{R}$ closed under multiplication, Ordered Field Axioms) this justifies the equivalence to $y<nx$ under your conditions.

Comment: Thank You! I can see the connection now.

Comment: I had a question. How would defining  satisfy the assumption of " for every  in real numbers"?

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment did not fully clarify your question, I give a complete answer.

Your lemma states that for every $z\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $z<n$.

Now this implies that for a positive real number $x>0$ the inequality $zx<nx$ holds under the same assumptions.

Now let $y\in\mathbb{R}$ be a real number and $x>0$. Then we can find a decomposition of $y=zx$ into a product of a positive number $x$ and a real number $z=y\cdot x^{-1}$. Therefore, we can use the variant of your lemma from above which gives $$y = zx< nx \; .$$Thus, for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and every positive number $x>0$ there exists a natural number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $y<nx$.

Comment: Note, that the single steps are justified by the (Ordered) Field Axioms.